# Strange error from integrate/uniroot

Tags: r, numerical-methods

So, I'm trying to compute the integral of the implicit function 
`fx01`

```
fx01<-function(y,z0)    pnorm(z0+y)-pnorm(z0-y)-0.5
fx11<-function(z0){
    uniroot(fx01,interval=c(0,10),z0=z0)$root
}
integrate(fx11,lower=1,upper=1.1)$value
```

and I get:

```
Error in uniroot(fx01, interval = c(0, 10), z0 = z0) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(f.lower)) stop("f.lower = f(lower) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.na(f.upper)) stop("f.upper = f(upper) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Now, I don't understand what is causing these errors: 
 the function `fx01` returns a bounded scalar for all 
 the values of `z0` in -infty +infty (it is the standard normal distribution) and if one checks:

```
interval=c(0,10)
fx01(min(interval),z0=1)
fx01(max(interval),z0=1)

fx01(min(interval),z0=1.1)
fx01(max(interval),z0=1.1)
```

The values **are** of opposite sign. What do these error messages mean in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fx11` function isn't properly vectorized. Try

```
integrate(Vectorize(fx11),lower=1,upper=1.1)$value
```

The problem is that `integrate` will pass in a vector of values at once to the function you are trying to integrate, it does not evaluate each point separately. Your function works when `z0` is of length one

```
uniroot(fx01,interval=c(0,10),z0=1)$root
# [1] 1.050555
```

but not when it's a vector of values

```
uniroot(fx01,interval=c(0,10),z0=c(1,1.05))$root
# Error in uniroot(fx01, interval = c(0, 10), z0 = c(1, 1.05)) : 
#   f() values at end points not of opposite sign
# In addition: Warning messages:
# 1: In if (is.na(f.lower)) stop("f.lower = f(lower) is NA") :
#   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
# 2: In if (is.na(f.upper)) stop("f.upper = f(upper) is NA") :
#   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

The `Vectorize()` function will run each value of `z0` separately.

Comment: Thank you sire: no way I would have figured this!