# R Solve equation - Error in uniroot(f, x = 2.326348, lower = 0.1, upper = 1e+08)

Tags: r

I am trying to solve in R the following equation :

```
2.326348 = Normal inverse function(y)
```

Normal Inverse Function is :

```
sqrt(-2*log(sqrt(2*pi)*y))
```

or more simply : `qnorm(y)`

So in order to solve the equation I used the function below :

```
f <- function(x,y)  (sqrt(-2*log(sqrt(2*pi)*y))-x)
uniroot(f, x=2.326348, lower=0.1, upper=100000000)$root
```

or

```
f <- function(x,y)  (qnorm(y)-x)
    uniroot(f, x=2.326348, lower=0.1, upper=100000000)$root
```

but this does return :

```
Error in uniroot(f, x = 2.326348, lower = 0.1, upper = 1e+08) : 
  f.upper = f(upper) is NA
```

What should I do in order to solve this equation ? I already [saw this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30445343/11167163) but it seems that its not the same issue.

[uniroot documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/uniroot)

Comment: if you run `f(2.326348, 100000000)`, you get `NaN` so either your limits or equation is incorrect

Comment: @rawr was thinking that limit would auto fit, thanks for clarification

Comment: @G.Grothendieck `dnorm(x)=0.02665213` and `y=0.99001` so `y is not equal to dnorm(x)` am I wrong ?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck is qnorm(y) = to normal inverse function ?

Comment: I have transferred my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition interval for `qnorm` is `[0,1]` and you're getting an error because you try to find a solution out of this interval.
If you limit the search to `[0,1]` it works :

```r
y = 2.326348
uniroot(function(x) qnorm(x)-y,lower=0, upper = 1)
#> $root
#> [1] 0.99001
#> 
#> $f.root
#> [1] 0.0003750975
#> 
#> $iter
#> [1] 11
#> 
#> $init.it
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $estim.prec
#> [1] 6.103516e-05
```

Comment: Working, but can you explain a bit ?

Comment: see my edit about definition interval for qnorm.

Comment: Thank you, was thinking that it would autofit interval

Comment: It is not true that qnorm(y) equals sqrt(-2*log(sqrt(2*pi)*y))

Comment: @G. Grotendeck, I didn't check this and followed what was asked by OP, but you're right, both uniroot don't give the same result which means the functions must be different.

Answer (score 2):

The question refers to both f and g below as if they were the same but they are not.   The solution to f(x, y) = 0 for fixed x is y = dnorm(x) and the solution to g(x, y) = 0 for fixed x is y = pnorm(x).  The expression to the left hand side of -x  in the body of f is the inverse of the gaussian probability density function (pdf) while that in g is the inverse of the gaussian cumulative probability distribution function (cdf).

```
f <- function(x, y) (sqrt(-2*log(sqrt(2*pi)*y))-x)
g <- function(x, y) qnorm(y) - x

x <- 2.326348

f(x, dnorm(x))
## [1] 0

g(x, pnorm(x))
## [1] 4.440892e-16
```

### 1. f

First we work with f above.

Square both sides and then it will behave better in uniroot. Also use 0 and 1 as the bounds.

```
x <- 2.326348
f2 <- function(x,y) -2*log(sqrt(2*pi)*y)-x^2
result <- uniroot(f2, x = x, lower = 0, upper = 1)
result
## $root
## [1] 0.02666295
##
## $f.root
## [1] -0.000811161
##
## $iter
## [1] 9
##
## $init.it
## [1] NA
##
## $estim.prec
## [1] 6.103516e-05
```

Compare the root above with

```
dnorm(x)
## [1] 0.02665213
```

### 2. g

Now we work with g above.

```
result2 <- uniroot(g, x = x, lower = 0, upper = 1)
result2
## $root
## [1] 0.99001
##
## $f.root
## [1] 0.0003750975
##
## $iter
## [1] 11
##
## $init.it
## [1] NA
##
## $estim.prec
## [1] 6.103516e-05
```

Compare the root above with pnorm(x)

```
pnorm(x)
## [1] 0.99
```

Comment: `f(x, result$root)` does not return the same value as your did you run it ?

Comment: I have expanded the answer.